# jQuery: Preventing and then not preventing form submit using the "live" method

Tags: forms, jquery

I am writing a form to be inserted in clients' webpages that is to be submitted with an AJAX request for processing. Then, depending on the client's settings, I want to either display a "Form Successfully Submitted" victory message, or I want to redirect the user to my site (by submitting the form to my site) for additional processing.

I'm using jQuery to try to get this to work. My strategy is to put a "live" binding to the submit event on my form, which then prevents the default submission and does a jQuery post using the form values as parameters for processing at my site. If the form passes validation AND its determined that the user needs to be redirected, the form submission is triggered again, but this time the submit handler returns true, which should enable the default, right? It does return true (I checked with alerts), but the form is not submitted. Here is sample code:

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- Elements in here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var handleSubmit = true;
    $("#myform").live('submit', function(){
        if (handleSubmit === true){
            $.post('http://example.org', $('#myform').serialize(), function(response){
                if (response.success){
                    if (response.redirect){
                        handleSubmit = false;
                        $('#myform').attr('action',response.redirect);
                        $('#myform').submit();
                    } else {
                        alert('success!');
                    }
                } else {
                    // replace form contents with response.html (the form w/ errors)
                }
            }, 'json');
            return false;
        } else {
            // submit form (default action)
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've tried different things like putting the submit trigger within a setTimeout, or using 'bind' instead of using live, but the result is the same.

One thing that is perhaps important to note is that the above code and the code for the form itself is also generated from an AJAX request from the client's site.

Any guidance you could give would be much appreciated. I am also definitely open to different ways of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying the entire handler above is pulled in via an ajax call? If so, the DOM ready event has already fired *before* the code is brought into your page via ajax, no?

Comment: True, I had it without the ready event originally, but was at my wit's end and threw it in there. But you're right -- I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Hopefully this is just a typo in your post, but there's no semicolon after                         $('#myform').attr('action',response.redirect)

Comment: Also, have you checked the new form action taken from the response? There could be something wrong there.

Comment: I simulated everything including when the form is loaded from AJAX and it runs perfectly fine. Is there other forms with the same id (#myform) on the page?

Comment: @KenRedler The `jQuery.ready()` function runs even on AJAX load.

Comment: there was indeed a semicolon there. Gotta get better at copying code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having is actually with the input element:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">`

The redirecting form submit is failing because names of form controls within a `form` element are exposed as properties of the `form` in the DOM and can cause conflicts with the `form`'s original properties. Conflicts like this will fail silently when triggering events through jQuery's event functions. Changing your `input` element to the following should fix the problem you're having:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: The `input` should be self-closing: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`

Comment: This is true for XHTML doctypes, but not HTML doctypes. There is no point in making assumptions about what doctype Will is using, especially if its not relevant to the problem.

Comment: I have to say I still don't quite understand why this happened, though. Are you saying the id/name attribute of this input was overriding form.submit? If so, that's odd that I've never run into this problem before.

Comment: Yes. This is a result of how javascript and the DOM API works. I've coded up an example that you can work through on jsbin to see for yourself: http://jsbin.com/idoya5/edit